# Animated.View + Pan Responder causes re-render for every pixel in React Native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, animation

I would like to implement pan gesture in UITableViewCell. I have successfully done so; however, the pan gesture causes `shouldUpdateComponent` to be called for every pixel.  (even though I store the `translateX` property as a class variable)

```
class ThreadCell extends React.Component {
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
        //Problem: This calls for every pixel moved.
        console.log("shouldComponentUpdate");
        return true;
    }
    translateX = new Animated.Value(0);
    panResponder = PanResponder.create({
        onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture: (e, gs) => { return true; },
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (e, gs) => {  return gs.dx > 0 },
        onPanResponderMove: (e, gestureState) => { 
            if(gestureState.dx > 0) { 
                this.props.setScrollEnabled(false)
                Animated.event([null, {dx: this.translateX}])(e, gestureState) 
            }
        },
        onPanResponderTerminate: (e, gestureState) => {
            console.log("terminate");            
            Animated.spring(this.translateX, {
                toValue: 0,
                bounciness: 1
            }).start();
        },
        onPanResponderRelease: (e, {vx, dx}) => {
            console.log("release. DX: ", dx);
            Animated.spring(this.translateX, {
                toValue: 0,
                bounciness: 8,
                speed:48,
            }).start((result) => {
                if(dx > 24){
                    this.props.onMenuSwipe(this.props.sectionTitle, this.props.threadId)                    
                }else{
                    console.log("nah");
                }
            });
        },
    });
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <View>
                <Animated.View
                    style={{transform: [{translateX: this.translateX}]}}  {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
                >
                <Text>Stuff Here</Text>
                </Animated.View>
            </View>
         )
     }
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you could add a working [snack](http://snack.expo.io) to debug the issue.

Comment: Add the parent component code (that passed the `setScrollEnabled` prop to ThreadCell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.props.setScrollEnabled(false)` is called in `onPanResponderMove`, which is called whenever the gesture moves.

`this.props.setScrollEnabled(false)` likely sets a state in the parent component, hence it re-renders, which in turn causes `shouldComponentUpdate` of all child components to be invoked (unless it's connected to Redux with `pure` config enabled).

You can move the `setScrollEnabled` to `onStartShouldSetPanResponder` so that it's only called at the start of the gesture:

```
onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (e, gs) => {
  if (gs.dx > 0) {
    this.props.setScrollEnabled(false);
  }
  return true;
},
```

Alternatively, check that the desired state change is different from the current state before calling `setState` in the parent component:

```
setScrollEnabled(enable) {
  if (this.state.enable !== enable) {
    this.setState({ enable });
  }
}
```